# Selecting specific date from pandas data-frame

Tags: python, pandas

From the daily stock price data, I want to sample and select end of the month price. I am accomplishing using the following code.

```
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas as pd

end = datetime.date.today()

begin=end-pd.DateOffset(365*2)

st=begin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

ed=end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')


data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL",st,ed)

mon_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Adj Close'].resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-2])).set_index(data.index)
```

The line above selects end of the month data and here is the output.

[image: Output of resampled data-frame]

If I want to select penultimate value of the month, I can do it using the following code.

```
mon_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Adj Close'].resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-2]))
```

Here is the output.

[image]

However the index shows end of the month value. When I choose penultimate value of the month, I want index to be 2015-12-30 instead of 2015-12-31. 
Please suggest the way forward. I hope my question is clear.

Thanking you in anticipation.

Regards,
Abhishek

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if there is a way to do it with resample. But, you can get what you want using groupby and TimeGrouper.

```
import datetime
from pandas_datareader import data as pdr
import pandas as pd

end = datetime.date.today()
begin = end - pd.DateOffset(365*2)
st = begin.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
ed = end.strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

data = pdr.get_data_yahoo("AAPL",st,ed)

data['Date'] = data.index
mon_data = (
    data[['Date', 'Adj Close']]
        .groupby(pd.TimeGrouper(freq='M')).nth(-2)
        .set_index('Date')
)
```

Answer (score 0):

simplest solution is to take the index of your newly created dataframe and subtract the number of days you want to go back:

```
n = 1   
mon_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Adj Close'].resample('M').apply(lambda x: x[-1-n])) 
mon_data.index = mon_data.index - datetime.timedelta(days=n)
```

also, seeing your data, i think that you should resample not to ' month end frequency' but rather to 'business month end frequency':

```
.resample('BM')
```

but even that won't cover it all, because for instance December 29, 2017 is a business month end, but this date doesn't appear in your data (which ends in December 08 2017). so you could add a small fix to that (assuming the original data is sorted by the date):

```
end_of_months = mon_data.index.tolist()
end_of_months[-1] = data.index[-1]
mon_data.index = end_of_months
```

so, the full code will look like:

```
n = 1  
mon_data=pd.DataFrame(data['Adj Close'].resample('BM').apply(lambda x: x[-1-n])) 

end_of_months = mon_data.index.tolist()
end_of_months[-1] = data.index[-1]
mon_data.index = end_of_months

mon_data.index = mon_data.index - datetime.timedelta(days=n)
```

btw: your `.set_index(data.index)` throw an error because `data` and `mon_data` are in different dimensions (`mon_data` is monthly grouped_by)

Comment: Nice solution. The OP asked for "penultimate value of the month" though. If the "penultimate value of the month" does not happen in the day before last business day of the month, this solution will not work.

Comment: you are right. your solution is better. was very happy to learn about this TimeGrouper. such a useful tool.

Comment: Thanks guys for the prompt response. I will go with Sina's solution. Thanks Idan for pointing out the error in my code.